# Syntax problem with sum operation in Java-Python translator

Tags: c, parsing, compiler-construction, syntax-error, flex-lexer

I'm trying to realize a Java-Python translator. I'm using flex to recognize some java tokens. I managed integer number with this regular expression:

```
...
digit   [0-9]
number  (\+|\-)?{digit}+
...
%%
...
{number} {yylval.i= atoi (yytext);return(NUMBER);}
 "+"     {return (ADD);}
```

In the parser I define this production :

```
ArithmeticExpression
                : ExpressionStatement ADD ExpressionStatement
                | ExpressionStatement SUB ExpressionStatement
                | ExpressionStatement MULT ExpressionStatement
                | ExpressionStatement DIV ExpressionStatement
                | ExpressionStatement MOD ExpressionStatement
                ;

ExpressionStatement
                   : NUMBER
                   ;
```

if I give in input to translator expressions like this:

```
int a = 5 ++67;  (syntax error in java)
```

how can I manage this situation so that 5 ++67 is recognized like an error and not like 5 + +67 (therefor an ArithmeticExpression) by the translator ?

Comment: You need to make `++` a token.

Comment: If you add `"++"` as an `INCREMENT` token, I think that should solve the problem.

Comment: I don't have to manage  prefix operators , I have to manage binary operators only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has already been said in the comments, you need to introduce a `++` token.

You say that you don't need to handle unary operators. Even so, you still need the token. `5 ++67` is an error in Java exactly because `++` is its own token. If it weren't, `5 ++67` would be equivalent to `5 + +67`. So if you want to get the same error as in Java in this case, you also need to have a `++` token - even if you never use it.